# using single style class for enabled and disabled button

Tags: css, button

I have a button which is using a class formBtn

in css

```
.formBtn {color:#fff; background-color:#518ACD; border-color:#ccc #000 #000 #ccc; font-    size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
```

in HTML

```
<html:submit styleClass="formBtn" value="Add"/>
```

Suggest me something so that I can use the same class name for a disabled button and show it in a different manner (say background-color:Grey). I may be using the style class like   this

in HTML

```
<html:submit styleClass="formBtn" value="Disabled Add" disabled="true"/>
```

Comment: I would suggest you doing this via server code. What platform are you using for your website application?

Answer (score 7):

Use the :disabled pseudoclass.

```
.formBtn:disabled { background-color: grey; }
```

Comment: Won't work in majority of IE's as these cannot understand pseudo classes besides the ones given to anchor.

Comment: Oh, I tend to be somewhat careless when it comes to IE as it usually doesn't do what I want it to do. Sorry D:

Comment: @eugeneK: IE can understand some pseudo-classes, and only IE6 doesn't understand `:hover` on non-anchors. But you're right in that `:disabled` isn't supported in IE.

Comment: @René you have a spelling mistake in backgrouund-color. Please fix, editing of posts is not allowed for me.

Answer (score 3):

[attribute=value] selector should work IE7, don't know about IE6 if you care.

```
.formBtn[disabled=true] { background: gray}
```

If you have "Disabled" word in values you could do something like:

```
.formBtn[value~=Disabled] { background: gray}
```

Comment: +1 I was wondering how to override my default styles and I didn't want to add another class dynamically AND have to add the disabled attribute at the same time with the backend. (Accidentally added this comment as an answer.)