# Jquery: Unchecked button if another button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

the question is too difficult for me:

I have two button:

**#Inca**
and
**#Maya**

If **#Inca** checked, i want disabled **#Inca** and to remove (if there is) the check on button **#Maya** .

But than, if i check **#Maya**, i want disabled **#Maya**, abled **#Inca** but to remove the check on button **#Inca** (but this doesn't work).

In this way if i want, i can check button #Inca and the "loop" start again.

This is the code:

```
$('#incas, #maya').change(function () {
    if ($('#incas').attr("checked")) {
         $('#incas').attr('disabled', true);
         $('#maya').attr('disabled', false);
    } 
    if ($('#maya').attr("checked")){
        $('#maya').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#incas').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#incas').attr('checked', false);             
    }
});
```

and this is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/es8p74w4/

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`, Code: `$('#inca, #support').not(this).prop('checked', false);`http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ovgcs7gh/. However you should use radio buttons

Comment: Use radio buttons instead of check boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use checkboxes in this case. Use radio buttons and you won't need any JS:

```html
<div id="noneAbove">
    <p>
        <input id="inca" name="foo" type="radio" />
inca    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="support" name="foo" type="radio" />Blah Blah</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class to enable and disable buttons: less code, more efficient and clean.

[using single style class for enabled and disabled button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975761/using-single-style-class-for-enabled-and-disabled-button)